# A generalization of Euler Factorization with $N = m a^2 + n b^2 = m c^2 + n d^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

In [Euler Factorization](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersFactorizationMethod.html), we try to represent a positive integer $N$ as the sum of two squares in two different ways i.e.,

$$
N = a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2
$$

Let
$$
\begin{align}
a-c & = kl, \\
d-b & = km, \\
(l,m) & = 1, \\
a+c & = mn, \\
b+d & = ln
\end{align}
$$

then Euler gave the formula:

$$
N = \left[\left(\frac{1}{2} k\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2} n\right)^2\right](l^2 + m^2)
$$

John Brillhart discusses a generalization of this method in [JB2009] by representing $N$ in two different ways as $N = m a^2 + n b^2 = m c^2 + n d^2$ and provides a proof in Theorem 2 in the note, reproduced below:

**Theorem 2 [JB2009].** Let $N > 1$ be an odd integer expressed in two different ways as

$$
N = m a^2 + n b^2 = m c^2 + n d^2, 
$$

where $a, b, c, d, m, n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}, b < d$ and $(ma, nb) = (mc, nd) = 1.$ Then

$$
N = (N, ad - bc) \cdot \frac{N}{(N, ad - bc)}.
$$

Proof omitted.

---

In an effort to find suitable $a, b, c, d, m, n$ for a given integer $N$, I am using the following procedure:

1. Choose $a, b$ such that $(a,b) = 1$.
2. Solve $$N = a^2 m + b^2 n \tag{1}$$ for $m, n$ using Extended Euclid's algorithm. This is the first representation of $N$.
3. If we fix $m, n$ and solve the equation $mX + nY = N$ then by the same Extended Euclid's algorithm, there are an infinite number of solutions for $X, Y$, provided $(m,n)=1$ (*Note: If $(m,n) \ne 1$ then the $(m,n)|N$*). We are looking for **square solutions** of the form

$$
\begin{align}
X = c^2 & = a^2 - nt, \\
Y = d^2 & = b^2 + mt, \\
t & \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

4. If $t = 2a - n = 2b + m$ then

$$
\begin{align}
c^2 & =a^2-n(2a-n)=a^2-2an+n^2=(a-n)^2, \\
d^2 & =b^2+m(2b+m)=b^2+2bm+m^2=(b+m)^2.
\end{align} \tag{3}
$$

$$
\therefore m+n = 2a - 2b \tag{4}
$$

is a sufficient condition for **square solutions** to exist.

5. Suppose $m_0, n_0$ is a solution to Eqn. $(1)$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
m & = m_0 - b^2 u, \\
n & = n_0 + a^2 u, \\
u & \in \mathbb{Z} 
\end{align} \tag{5}
$$

6. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
m+n & =m_0+n_0+a^2 u-b^2 u \\
\implies 2(a-b) & =m_0+n_0+(a^2-b^2 )u \\
\implies (a-b)(2-(a+b)u) & =m_0+n_0
\end{align} \tag{6}
$$

7. Solve for $u$ in Eqn. $(6)$ and substitute in Eqn. $(5)$ to get $m, n$.
8. Substitute $m, n$ in Eqn. $(3)$ to get $c, d$.
9. Factorize $$N = (N, ad - bc) \cdot \frac{N}{(N, ad - bc)}.$$

The effectiveness of this procedure hinges on the choice of $a, b$ such that in Step 6. we can find an integer solution for $u$ by solving

$$
(a-b)(2-(a+b)u) = m_0+n_0 \tag{7}
$$

**Question:**

1. How does one effectively choose $a,b$ so that Eqn. $(7)$ can be solved in integers for $u$?

One idea is to choose $a,b$ to be consecutive integers so that $a - b = 1$ and $(a,b)=(a,a-1)=1$ which ensures $m_0, n_0$ exists and then Eqn. $(7)$ becomes

$$
\begin{align}
m_0+n_0 & = (a-b)(2-(a+b)u) \\
 & = 1 \cdot (2-(a+b)u) \\
 & = 2-(a+a-1)u \\
\implies (2a-1)u & = 2 - m_0 - n_0 \\
\implies u & = \frac{2 - m_0 - n_0}{2a-1}
\end{align}
$$

So, this now reduces to choosing suitable $a$ such that $2a-1$ divides $2 - m_0 - n_0$.

2. In step 3, what is the guarantee that there exist **square solutions** for Eqn. $(2)$

---

**An update (Jul 7, 2023):**

Let $K$ be a rational number such that

$$
\begin{align}
N&=ma^2+nb^2=m(K-a)^2+n(K-b)^2 \\
&=m(K^2-2Ka+a^2 )+n(K^2-2Kb+b^2 ) \\
&=K^2 (m+n)-2K(am+bn)+(ma^2+nb^2 ) \\
&=K^2 (m+n)-2K(am+bn)+N
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
K^2 (m+n)=2K(am+bn) \\
K=2\left(\frac{am+bn}{m+n}\right)
$$

i.e., if $(m+n) | 2(am+bn)$ then $K$ is an integer then we *may* have the two required representations of $N$.

So, factoring $N$ may be reduced to finding $a, b, m, n$ such that $(m+n) | 2(am+bn)$.

Also, suppose the two representations are unique. Then, by Brillhart, a non-trivial divisor can be found using $(N, ad - bc)$.

i.e.,

$$
\begin{align}
ad - bc & = a(K-b) - b(K-a) \\
& = aK - ab - bK + ab \\
& = (a-b)K
\end{align}
$$

So, the non-trivial divisor is $(ad - bc, N) = ((a-b)K, N)$.

The question still remains. How do we choose $a, b, m, n$?

---

**An update (Jul 11, 2023):**

The method in [HMW1990] gives an algorithm for solving $n = fu^2 + g\upsilon^2$ in coprime integers $u$ and $\upsilon$.

It has running time $O\left(n^{\frac{1}{4}} (\log n)^3 (\log \log n) (\log \log \log n)\right)$.

We could use this algorithm to find $N = ma^2 + nb^2 = mc^2 + nd^2$ and then apply the Brillhart theorem to compute a non-trivial factor with a simple GCD.

---

**References**

[JB2009]: Brillhart, J. (2009). A Note on Euler’s Factoring Problem. *The American Mathematical Monthly, 116*(10), 928–931. http://www.jstor.org/stable/40391253

[HMW1990]: Hardy, K., Muskat, J. B., & Williams, K. S. (1990). A Deterministic Algorithm for Solving $n = fu^2 + g\upsilon^2$ in Coprime Integers $u$ and $\upsilon$. *Mathematics of Computation, 55*(191), 327–343. https://doi.org/10.2307/2008809

Comment: This looks very similar to my question here : 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722548/the-diophantine-equation-a2-p-b2-c2-p-d2-q-and-related-ring-theo

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an effective procedure for finding $a,b,c,d,m,n\in \mathbb Z^+$
> such that we can apply the factorization method of Brillhart given in the reference?

If I understand your question correctly, the following should help.

Let us start with
$$m a^2 + n b^2 = m c^2 + n d^2\tag1$$

$(1)$ can be written as
$$m(a-c)(a+c)=n(d-b)(d+b)\tag2$$

Now, there are integers $k,p,q$ such that
$$a-c=pk,\qquad d-b=qk,\qquad (p,q)=1$$

So, from $(2)$, we have
$$mps=nqt$$
where $a+c=s$ and $d+b=t$.

So, under the condition that $(m,n)=1$, there is an integer $r$ such that
$$ps=rn,\qquad qt=rm$$
where $r=(ps,qt)$ and
$$m=\frac{qt}{(ps,qt)},\qquad n=\frac{ps}{(ps,qt)}$$

Therefore, we finally get
$$a=\frac{pk+s}{2},\qquad b=\frac{t-qk}{2},\qquad c=\frac{s-pk}{2},\qquad d=\frac{t+qk}{2}$$
$$m=\frac{qt}{(ps,qt)},\qquad n=\frac{ps}{(ps,qt)}$$

and
$$\begin{align}N&=ma^2+nb^2
\\\\&=\frac{qt}{(ps,qt)}\bigg(\frac{pk+s}{2}\bigg)^2+\frac{ps}{(ps,qt)}\bigg(\frac{t-qk}{2}\bigg)^2
\\\\&=\frac{qt(p^2k^2+2pks+s^2)+ps(t^2-2tqk+q^2k^2)}{4(ps,qt)}
\\\\&=\frac{st(sq+tp)+k^2pq(sq+tp)}{4(ps,qt)}
\\\\&=\frac{(st+k^2pq)(sq+tp)}{4(ps,qt)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. So, if we start with a given $N$, say $N = 1387$, we choose the parameters $p, q, s, t, k$. If we fix $p,q,s,t,k$ then $a,b,c,d$ are fixed and therefore $m, n$ are fixed because of the system of equations $a^2m + b^2n = c^2m + d^2n = N$. How do we pick $p,q,s,t,k$? (without factoring $N$).

Comment: @vvg : What I did is similar to Euler Factorization, but I realized that what you want is something different. Your question looks very difficult. If you know how to pick $k,l,m,n$ such that $N=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=\left[\left(\frac{1}{2} k\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2} n\right)^2\right](l^2 + m^2)$ without factoring $N$, can you show how? That should be helpful for our generalization.

Comment: @vvg : I think that your step 4. can be improved, but it still seems difficult to choose $a,b$ such that $u$ is an integer. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: @vvg : I've spent a lot of time looking for good results, but to no avail. In your step 4., if $t=2as-ns^2=2bs+ms^2$, we have $a^2-nt=(a-sn)^2$ and $b^2+mt=(b+ms)^2$. So, $2(a-b)=(m+n)s$ (where $s$ is a divisor of $2(a-b)$) is a sufficient condition for square solutions to exist.